# Split data in TD into it's own TR

Tags: php, html-table

Currently have this result

```
<tr class="odd">

      <td>Type:</td>

<td>basic<br>white<br>4s<br><br>basic<br>white<br>4s<br><br>basic<br>white<br>4s<br><br>basic<br>white<br>4s<br><br>basic<br>white<br>4s<br><br>basic<br>white<br>4s<br><br>basic<br>whirw<br>4s<br><br>basic<br>white<br>4s<br><br>basic<br>white<br>4s<br><br>basic<br>white<br>4s<br><br>basic<br>white<br>4s<br><br>basic<br>white<br>4s<br><br>basic<br>white<br>4s<br><br>basic<br>white<br>4s<br><br>basic<br>white<br>4s<br><br>basic<br>white<br>4s</td>

    </tr>
```

Using this PHP

```
<tr class="' . ($counter++ % 2 ? "odd" : "even") . '">

  <td>Type:</td>

  <td>' . str_replace(' ', '<br />', trim($result['garment_type'] ) ) . '</td>

</tr>
```

Is there any way to make any text after the double breaks its own TR and TD? Something like this below

```
<tr class="odd">

      <td>Type:</td>

<td>basic<br>white<br>4s</td>

    </tr>
```

Comment: It would be more useful if you would provide the (sample) value(s) for `$result['garment_type']`, and the PHP loop you generate this in. Also, it is impossible to generate `class="garments"` from that PHP code snippet.

Comment: what is the output of `trim($result['garment_type'] ) )`

Comment: @trincot edited to include proper class. Sample value would be the above code with the breaks.

Comment: Output of garment_type is all the data in td without breaks.

Comment: Again, `<tr class="garments">` is impossible to come from your PHP. Please provide the loop code you have, with sample data for `$result['garment_type']`, which is not what you provided, since you are applying a `replace` on it. Also, your `replace` is inserting `<br/>` with a slash, which does not occur in your output... You are in fact not providing PHP code, and want us to write it for you?

Comment: Edited again to include proper classes

Comment: Never said that but that is the code inside my php file